# How to differentiate $f(x,y(x))$ with respect to $x$?

Tags: calculus

Assuming $y(x)$ is differentiable.

Then, what is formula for differentiation ${d\over dx}f(x,y(x))$?

I examine some example but get no clue....

Comment: did you try the chain rule?

Answer (score 3):

There are two pieces to this: $f$ is a function of $x$ and a function of $y$ which suggests use of the chain rule. The multivariate chain rule says

$$\frac{d}{dx}f(x,y(x)) = \frac{\partial f}{\partial x}+\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}\frac{dy}{dx}.$$

More generally, if you have a function $f(x,y,\ldots,z)$ and the variables $x,y,\ldots,z$ depend on $t$, then

$$\frac{d}{dt}f(x(t),y(t),\ldots, z(t)) = \frac{\partial f}{\partial x}\frac{dx}{dt}+\frac{\partial y}{\partial t}+\cdots+\frac{\partial f}{\partial z}\frac{dz}{dt}.$$

(Your case is $x(t) = t$.)

---

For example, consider $f(x,y) = \sqrt{x^2+y^2}$ and $y(x) = x^2$, then $f(x,y(x)) = \sqrt{x^2+(x^2)^2} = \sqrt{x^2+x^4}.$ If we simply compute the derivative with this new expression for $f$, we get

$$\frac{df}{dx} = \frac{2x+4x^3}{2\sqrt{x^2+x^4}} = \frac{x+2x^3}{\sqrt{x^2+x^4}}.$$

Let's try using the equation I gave up above to see if it matches.

$$\frac{df}{dx} = \frac{\partial f}{\partial x}+\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}\frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}+\frac{y(x)}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}\cdot 2x = \frac{x+2xy(x)}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}} = \frac{x+2x^3}{\sqrt{x^2+x^4}}.$$

They agree as they should.

Answer (score 0):

First, compute $\mathrm{d}f(x,z)$ without assuming any relationship between $x,z$.  Suppose you compute this to be

$$ \mathrm{d} f(x,z) = f_1(x,z) \mathrm{d}x + f_2(x,z) \mathrm{d}z $$

Now, we can substitute in the dependence $z = y(x)$. We need

$$ \mathrm{d}z = y'(x) \mathrm{d}x $$

and now substituting, we get

$$\begin{align} \mathrm{d} f(x, y(x)) 
&= f_1(x, y(x)) \mathrm{d}x + f_2(x, y(z)) y'(x) \mathrm{d} x
\\&= \left(f_1(x, y(x)) + f_2(x, y(z)) y'(x) \right)\mathrm{d} x \end{align}$$

from which we infer

$$ \frac{\mathrm{d} f(x, y(x))}{\mathrm{d} x} = f_1(x, y(x)) + f_2(x, y(z)) y'(x) $$

Comment: Incidentally, you don't have to read answer as $f_1$ and $f_2$ having any special meaning; it's fine to read them as simply being placeholders for two functions you'd compute when finding the total differential. However, it is one of the standard notations for partial differentiaion, and is much more analogous to the notation $f'(x)$ for the derivative of a univariate function (evaluated at $x$) than other notations often used.

Answer (score 0):

You're substituting $c(t)=(t,y(t))$ in $f$.  Hence $(f\circ c)'(t)=\langle \nabla f(c(t),c'(t)\rangle$.